# Menu Item not detecting users' click on action_finish button

Tags: android, android-studio, menuitem

I have a ScreenSlideActivity.java sliding fragments with a pager. Since I want to create a tutorial with the Screen Slide Animation, I want to navigate the user back to the main activity when he presses the "finish" button. 
My problem is that the menu item inside onOptionsItemSelected doesn't detect the user's pressure on the "finish" button. This is my code:

In the onCreateOptionsMenu, I append three buttons: "Previous", "Next" and "Finish", and add either a "next" or "finish" button to the to the action bar depending on which page is currently selected.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

    // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
    // is currently selected.
    MenuItem item = menu.add(
            Menu.NONE,
            R.id.action_next,
            Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) 
                            ? R.string.action_finish : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}
```

Then within onOptionsItemSelected I handle the interaction with the three buttons

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
            // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_previous:
            // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
            // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:
            // Advance to the next step in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
            // will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_finish:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The "previous" button is created within "activity_screen_slide.xml":

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Adds an item to the list. -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_previous"
    android:title="@string/action_previous"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

While the other two are just created as ids in "ids.xml":

```
<resources>
<!--
    These action bar item IDs (menu item IDs) are defined here for
    programmatic use. Normally, IDs are created using the "@+id/foo"
    syntax,
    but since these IDs aren't created in menu XML, rather
    used for programmatically-instantiated action bar items, they
    are defined here.
-->
<item type="id" name="action_flip" />
<item type="id" name="action_next" />
<item type="id" name="action_finish" />
```

Then I got 
    Previous
    Next
    Finish
inside my string.xml file.

Therefore the "previous" button is the only one being defined in the menu layout file; the "next" button and the "finish" button are both present just as ids, but this doesn't doesn't seem to be a problem for the "next" button as it does for the "finish" button.
Why doesn't it work the same with the "finish" button?

*EDIT: SOLVED*

> The solution worked this way:

```
    MenuItem item = menu.add(
            Menu.NONE,   
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.id.action_finish : R.id.action_next, 
            Menu.NONE,   
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)  
            ? R.string.action_finish : R.string.action_next);  
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mention `the menu item inside onOptionsMenuSelected doesn't detect...`. I cannot seem to locate that method. Perhaps you mean `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: Oh, my bad, you are utterly right. I just corrected it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

The second parameter in the add() method of the menu object `itemId` mentions:

`Unique item ID. Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.`

The ID you assign to the button is `R.id.action_next`. You indeed have a condition but on the last parameter `titleRes` which is the `Resource identifier of title string`. Therefore you only change titles on the menu item that you insert to your menu when you should **also** change the second parameter of the `add()` method that is the item's ID.

**Conclusion:** There must be another conditional assignment on the second parameter of your `menu.add()` method that operates the same way as the one on your fourth parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer, it worked this way:

```
    MenuItem item = menu.add(
            Menu.NONE,   
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.id.action_finish : R.id.action_next, 
            Menu.NONE,   
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)  
            ? R.string.action_finish : R.string.action_next);  
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}
```